# For what positive integer values $n$, is $2^n+1$ divisible by 3

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, congruence-relations

For what positive integer values $n$, is $2^n+1$ divisible by 3, but I am not sure how to proceed.

The only thing I can depict is that: $2^n-1 \equiv 0 \pmod{3} \implies 2^n \equiv -1 \pmod{3}$

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint:

$$2 \equiv -1 \pmod 3$$

$$2^n \equiv (-1)^n \pmod 3$$

Comment: I was thinking that but my understanding of the concepts are not so well so do you think you can elaborate a bit?

Comment: $2^n + 1 \equiv (-1)^n + 1 \pmod 3$. For what values of $n$ is this expression $0 \pmod 3$?

Comment: think of what are the values that $(-1)^n$ can take? when do they take each of those values?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh $-1$ if $n$ is odd and $1$ if $n$ is even. But I still don't follow.

Comment: Notice that we have $2^n-1 \equiv 0 \pmod{3} \iff 2^n \equiv (-1)^n \equiv -1 \pmod{3}$

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh I think my math is too poor I I still don't get it. I understand your statement but the only thing I can think about is that $2^n \equiv -1 \pmod{3}$ is not possible.

Comment: @Omari $2^1\equiv -1\pmod{3}$ is true.  So too is $2^3\equiv -1\pmod{3}$.  Notice for example $2^3= 8 = 9-1=3\cdot 3-1$.

Comment: @JMoravitz I guess I had the concept wrong as I thought it was that $a \equiv b \pmod{c}$ meand that $a \mod{c} = b \mod{c}$, is that not so?

Comment: @OmariCelestine It might help to remember the *definition* of being equivalent modulo 3.  We say that $a\equiv b\pmod{3}$ if and only if $a-b$ is a multiple of $3$.  For example $2^3-(-1)=8-(-1)=8+1=9$ is indeed a multiple of three.  In pure mathematics, modulo is not an operation, it is an *equivalence relation*.  So, the question of if $2^n\equiv -1\pmod{3}$ is a question of if and when $2^n+1$ is a multiple of three.

Comment: $8 \equiv -1 \pmod 3$ because $8-(-1) \equiv 9 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$, $8$ and $-1$ share the same remainder when they are divided by $3$.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Isn't the remainder of $\frac{8}{3}$ equal to 2 and for $\frac{-1}{3}$ equal to $-1$?

Comment: @OmariCelestine if you insist on thinking in terms of fractions (*which I strongly discourage*) then you need to be consistent with how you are doing it.  A remainder must be strictly between $0$ and $n-1$.  Alternatively the proper fraction part of the number must be strictly positive.  $-1=-1\cdot3+2$.  Similarly $\frac{-1}{3}=-1+\frac{2}{3}$.  Likewise $8=2\cdot 3+2$ and $\frac{8}{3}=2+\frac{2}{3}$

Answer (score 2):

Let $a\in\{0,1\}$. Then
$$
1 + 2^{2n+a} = 1 + 2^a4^n = 1 + 2^a(1+3)^n = 1 + 2^a\sum_{k=0}^n\binom n k 3^k = 1 + 2^a + 3\sum_{k=1}^n\binom n k3^{k-1}.
$$

Comment: @WlodAA and... if $a=0$ then you have $1+1+3(\cdots)$.  If $a=1$ then you have $1+2+3(\cdots)$.

Comment: @JMoravitz, thank you.